# cumulative sum of differences

Tags: sqlite, cumulative-sum

Is it possible to summarize in sqlite as it does excel?
Here's a picture of what I want to do but only in sqlite:

[image: picture of what I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not have windowing functions, so you have to construct a set-based computation.

You want to get the sum of all previous differences, i.e., the sum of the differences in all rows that have the same or a smaller ID:

```
SELECT id,
       d,
       k,
       (SELECT sum(d - k)
        FROM MyTable AS T2
        WHERE T2.id <= MyTable.id
       ) AS cumulative_sum
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY id;
```